# Implementing a automated DB25 switch

Tags: switches

I currently have an application that uses a DB25 switch to switch signals between two devices (it's not actually a parallel port - there are analog and digital signals as well as DC power on the DB25). The manual switch box uses a big rotary switch and I would like to miniaturize this on a PCB. However, short of using 25 relays, does anyone have any suggestions on what type of switch I could use? The only caveat is that the solution must be break-before-make.
The signals include:
- -10V to 10V analog waveforms @ 100 KHz
- 0V / 5V TTL logic signals @ 500 KHz
- 5V 12V 24V DC power @ maximum 1A

Comment: A thorough explanation of the voltage ranges and acceptable series resistance on each of the signals is appropriate. We cannot give you a solution unless we know exactly what your signals are tolerant of. For instance, you might need to use MOSFETs or relays for DC power, but can you might be able to use muxes or digital crosspoint switches for the digital signals.

Comment: Updated to include signal types and voltage ranges

Comment: And what series resistances can the analog signals tolerate?

Comment: There are worse solutions than multipole relays. You don't need 25 single pole relays :)

Comment: What exactly does "miniaturize this on a PCB" mean?  Do you mean that you need something physically smaller?  Do you need to replace the existing switch for some reason?  Do you want to make this function controllable (as from a remote switch or a computer, etc?  Do you need "latching", or only switched while power is applied?  Truthfully, 13 DIP-size DPDT relays would probably be your most logical solution. (As suggested by Mr. Bland)  Examples: http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/category/500200/relays/dip/1.html

Comment: Thanks! My main goal is remote control, not necessarily smaller. Right now i am using the common / standard DB25 AB switch box. But what I really need is computer / remote digital control (i.e the PCB takes a TTL signal from an external source or a USB 1-bit blaster). Functionality is only required when powered.

Comment: Putting this question on hold makes no sense. I asked for "type of switch", which last I checked is not "a specific product." Unless you consider "use 13 DPDT relays" to somehow be "a specific product and place the purchase them." I actually got the answers I wanted before you thoughtlessly closed this question. "How do I solve this problem" actually maps to "what kind of component do I use," which in this case is "DPDT relay, no snubber." Nothing to do with "what vendor's relay should I buy."

Answer (score 1):

There is a company that makes large-count switches and relays: T-Bar.  They make a nice 24-pole relay that would be perfect. Except that it costs US$761!  However there is a 48PDT relay currently on Ebay for $25 if you are fast enough to grab it:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/8447-T-Bar-Switch-Relay-8501-3023-43-94-ohms-24-VDC-FREE-Shipping-Conti-USA-/311310900801

Comment: This answer will obviously be out of date pretty soon...

Comment: @pipe at least the impression of the pricing will be rather persistent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question, but here are some suggestions:

- As some have said, relays are a good solution. For the power and analog signals, these might be your best bet.
- For power, you could also use either discrete MOSFETs, MOSFET switches, or even SSRs. However, whether these are appropriate depends on how low of an on resistance you require.
- For digital and analog signals, you could use analog muxes/switches. There are plenty of options here as well, it's easy to find analog switches that can handle ±10V at frequencies well past 1MHz.
- For the digital signals, digital muxes/switches would probably work. There are bidirectional switches/muxes if you require bidirectional digital lines.

Basically, there are literally *thousands* of components that might be appropriate. Your choices are going to depend on size constraints, target BOM cost, and many other things.

Comment: Not sure if I am supposed to make this a new question but: does each relay need it's own snubber? So for 25 signals I need 13 relays and 13 snubbers?

Comment: Depends on the load. If you have reactive loads, yes. For signals, no.